# Is it possible to do mysql replication with one server in internet and another in a intranet?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I have a server in internet that must have all data synced (dont need to be in realtime) from a server from a intranet (obviously has internet connection). Is it possible?

How about sync both sides, master-master?

I havent tried yet because my internal server is behind a NAT and I dont have access to it.

Comment: Have you tried?  What did you try, and what happened?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman I havent tried yet because my problem is how can I sent data from internet to intranet, as my internal server is behind a NAT and I dont have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do it:

1. Configure the NAT router to forward the MySQL port (3306/tcp) from the internet to your intranet server.  In general this is a risky thing to do; obviously you don't want the whole internet to be able to connect to your database server.  So you'll need strong authentication, and strong encryption too as EEAA said.
2. Have a client inside the LAN connect out by ssh to the internet server, then tunnel port 3306 over that connection back to the intranet MySQL server:

   ```
   ssh -R 3306:intranetmysql:3306 internetmysql
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a server in internet that must have all data synced (dont need
>   to be in realtime) from a server from a intranet (obviously has
>   internet connection). Is it possible?

Yes.

> How about sync both sides, master-master?

Yes.

You need to consider encryption, though, as you don't want cleartext data going out over the internet.

Comment: Will also need to consider bandwidth requirements.  A large heavily used db with a 56k modem between the servers will never catch up.